# maxscript script controller for variables

Tags: parameters, controller, real-time, maxscript

I'm a newbie in maxscript and newbie in programming at all.

But I'm trying to find out is there a way to wire:
1) custom **Variables** and object parameters in real time
2) Structure properties and object parameters
3) "Two ways" connectivity between an amount of objects and custom Variables.

As far as I know, I'm able only to connect objects.pos objects.transform and so on. with Script controller. Or to wire two parameters which I could get in a scene.

But I'm trying to change my custom variables on the fly. In order to use structs with its properties.

Answer (score 0):

Using script controller, you can get (and in some cases set) anything that's accessible from global scope. That said, there's a reason nobody does that - those variables and struct instances have to exist before the scripted controller first fires, which usually means right after opening the scene, merging an object using that controller etc. You can work around the first case by making the variables persistent. This works well enough when they hold a reference to some of the objects available by default but will fail with custom struct unless you make sure their definitions are evaluated beforehands - so now you have one more file to distribute with the .max file together with the instructions on where to put it.

Instead, use custom attributes. They make it easy to store almost anything, from ints, floats, colors, maps, materials to objects and referenceTargets. You can also use locals (limited to the current session lifetime), functions and structs inside them (struct instances' lifetime is once again limited to current session only).

What to attach them to and how to access them depends on the task at hand, there's no universal solution. If you have a particular scenario in mind, make that a new question and try to be as specific as possible.

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer!
I think, I'm going to explain the purpose I'm looking for.

Comment: I'm trying to create a procedural Ui-setup (or control panel) for setting up a Facial rig setup, based on Morph targets.
   The key thing here is, that I'm introducing the concept of "Intension" wich means, in this case, a max. face-part translation. For example:
- I've got a human face with a Morpher modifier applied to it
- got 10 sliders wired to a certain Morph Channel
- Now once I drag one of the slider up - the others try to keep the master Intension value, by decreasing its current values. Because the sum of all sliders less than or equal to the master Value (100)

Comment: While wiring is nice for simple tasks, you should think twice before using it for more complex problems. What I'd do here is get rid og the viewport slider controls, throw an attribute holder modifier atop together with a custom attributes instance for the UI. Then it's easy to handle correcting the UI sliders' values on slider change and only after that update the morpher.